# How to use every language like cyrillic, arabian,chinese, english ... in same document?

Tags: languages

I build an application which generates pdfs via latex. I made a template tex files were i add the content from my application. Is there any way i can define my template tex file to support all kind of languages like chinese, cyrillic,  arabian etc?

I searched the web and found different solutions for every language which dont work together for all languages in one tex file.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Unfortunately in LaTeX this seems very complicated. Apparently one could use lualatex/xelatex with polyglossia with explicit mark-up for telling which language is used locally, but I think one has to inform polyglossia in preamble of which languages are used in document, else it is not possible that suitable fonts are loaded. Indeed you need OpenType font supporting the language. LaTeX allows to load fonts only in preamble. Thus the preamble must already know which fonts it will need in the document.